# Is there a limit to how much profit one should make

Tags: halacha, money, transactions

Should one refrain from excessive profit, such as when one charges 800 dollars or more for an item made for under ten dollars.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150485/discussion-on-question-by-raul-valdez-jr-is-there-a-limit-to-how-much-profit-on); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.